# How are these operators affecting this simple javascript program?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, operators

This is probably embarrassingly obvious but I can't seem to figure it out: I've researched what all of these operators mean and commented out what I think they're doing. Apparently total = 55. I thought it would = 11. Where am I going wrong? Thanks a lot.

```
var total = 0; 
var count = 1;

while (count <= 10) { // while "count" is less than or equal to 10 do...
  total += count; // total = total + count (total = 0 + count)
  count += 1; // count = 1 + 1 (adding 1 to count every loop until count is equal to 11)
};

console.log(total); -> 55

// total is 0 + count
// when the program ends count = 11
// 0 + 11 = 11
```

Comment: Have you tried writing down the values on a piece of paper and seeing how the additions work? Note that those assignments **change** the values of `total` and `count`, so on the second time through the loop `total` is not `0`.

Comment: `total += count` in a loop is `total = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 10`, which is 55.

Comment: you could have also added console.log() statements inside loop i.e. console.log(total) & console.log(count) to dry run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have stated in the comments.  You are incrementing your `count` and `total`.  Do one or the other.

Here's what your code is currently doing:

```js
var total = 0;
var count = 1;
var iteration = 0;
var div = document.getElementById("div");
while (count <= 10) {
  total += count;
  count += 1;
  iteration++;
  div.innerHTML += "Iteration " + iteration + ":  ";
  div.innerHTML += "count = " + count + "; ";
  div.innerHTML += "total = " + total + ";<br /><br />"
};
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

There's several ways you can do this.

One way would be to just increment the count and total by one at each iteration:

```js
var total = 0; 
var count = 1;
while (count <= 10) { // while "count" is less than or equal to 10 do...
  total++ // Increase the total by 1
  count++ // Increase the count by 1
};
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

but this only gives you a result of `10` because your count is starting at `1`

Another way would be to just increment your count, then assign your count to your total outside of the loop:

```js
var total = 0; 
var count = 1;
while (count <= 10) { // while "count" is less than or equal to 10 do...
  count++ // Increase the count by 1
};
total = count;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Or, remove `count` altogether:

```js
var total = 0;
while (total <= 10) {
  total++;
};
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Or, my preferred method, would be to change your loop from a `while` to a `for` loop

```js
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  total++;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is happening, try to write:

```
console.log(total);
console.log(count);
```

Inside of the while loop body.

You will see how it behaves on every iteration.

```
count += 1;
```

means:

```
count = count + 1;
```